# I need to improve my model

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb

I create a smaller app that has to be used for money transactions where it focuses on favor and expense from bank accounts (later I will expand other tables for admin, workers costs, credit calculations tables, etc) I already have several mistakes in the model and now I am starting to develop the backend (Spring boot) but I found the model is not good (again).

Table `exchange_rate` will takes from API for that date how much is currency and record it in DB. Because I need for every day, when the transaction happens, to know how much is that in euros or other currency and I want to have history what exchange rate was.

I get suggestions that `favor`(income) and `expense`(outcome) are the same and to create one table `transaction` is better than how I first created it. I think it will be useful to have columns in a new table `transaction` such as: `expense_amount` and `favor_amount`, what do you think?

My model how looks now (I need tips on how to improve and be proud of it :)).
I use **MariaDB**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cash`.`bank` (
  `bank_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bank_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cash`.`account` (
  `account_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `account_number` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
  `initial_state` DECIMAL(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `bank_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
  INDEX `fk_bank_statement_id_idx` (`bank_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `account_number_UNIQUE` (`account_number` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bank_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`bank_id`)
    REFERENCES `cash_flow_management`.`bank` (`bank_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cash`.`expense` (
  `expense_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `amount` DECIMAL(15,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb3' NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `account_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`expense_id`),
  INDEX `fk_currency_expense_currency_id_idx` (`currency_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_currency_expense_currency_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`)
    REFERENCES `cash_flow_management`.`currency` (`currency_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_account_expense_account_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`)
    REFERENCES `cash_flow_management`.`account` (`account_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cash`.`favor` (
  `favor_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `amount` DECIMAL(15,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb3' NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `account_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`favor_id`),
  INDEX `fk_currency_favor_currency_id_idx` (`currency_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_currency_favor_currency_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`)
    REFERENCES `cash_flow_management`.`currency` (`currency_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_account_favor_account_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`)
    REFERENCES `cash_flow_management`.`account` (`account_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cash`.`currency` (
  `currency_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`currency_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cash`.`exchange_rate` (
  `exchange_rate_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `amount` DECIMAL(15,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`exchange_rate_id`),
  INDEX `currency_exchange_rate_currency_id_idx` (`currency_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `currency_exchange_rate_currency_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`)
    REFERENCES `cash_flow_management`.`currency` (`currency_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cash`.`reserved_asset` (
  `reserved_asset_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `amount` DECIMAL(15,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reserved_asset_id`),
  INDEX `fk_currency_reserved_asset_currency_id_idx` (`currency_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_currency_reserved_asset_currency_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`)
    REFERENCES `cash_flow_management`.`currency` (`currency_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

`bank` will exist 2,3 four different banks.
`account` it will exist several accounts from different banks it will be domestic currency and foreign currency (euro, dollar, etc).
`currency` just to know what currency is it.
`reserved_assets` are something that will be needed for the current month.
For now, I will not have users but any tips will be useful to know for the future.
I have plans to put the history of updates but I don't know how to do that and I omit the update_on for every table.

p.s. I think I don't need constraints for FK (ON DELETE RESTRICT, ON UPDATE CASCADE) because I can override with Spring data JPA, right?

Answer (score 1):

A simplification... `currency` is a separate table to 'normalize' the names of currencies.  Yet it is using a 4-byte `INT` for each, versus a 3-byte standard code for the actual name.  Suggest you get rid of the table and just use the code in the other tables.  (Ditto for `country_code` and many other things that one is tempted to normalize.)

Will you ever use the column `created_at`?

Money is tricky.  Whereas `DECIMAL(15,4)` is probably good, do check the possible currencies you might be involved with -- to see whether 4 decimal places and a max of 100 billion are enough.

A common mistake is to create single-column indexes for many columns.  But I can't point at any specific problems without seeing the main queries that will be applied to the tables.

For banking-type apps, I like to have two tables -- a "history" and a "current" for "transactions".  The former is "write-once" and keeps an auditable record of everything that changes.  The latter keeps track of the *current* balances in each account.  Sure, `current` can be computed from `history`, but it is messy and clumsy and slow.

Exchange rate -- Don't you need two currencies?  Are you assuming "dollars" as the base?  Or something else?  And is just a "date" sufficient?  Perhaps the transaction should include the "exchange rate used for this transaction"?

What is a "favor" in this application?  Is it a "bribe"?  Or something "under the table"?

Comment: `created_at` is just for history, I don't see the reason right now why I need it. In general, for what is really useful? I saw every model has it.--- `history` and 'current` how should they look?--- For the exchange rate, I will need several currencies and have to know how much is euro or other currency on a specific date.---- The `favor` should tell me something as income, I think I will change expense to outcome and favor to income. I probably choose the wrong word to represent it.

Comment: <opinion>"Created/updated/etc_at" is a "solution waiting for a problem".</opinion>.  As for currency -- History can say, for example, that "X" "EUR" and the conversion "rate"; elsewhere would be the "USD" credited/debited to the account (after conversion).  In the US, I think "expense" and "income" are the preferred terms for "out" and "in".  "Debit" and "credit" are also used.  Or it may be practical to have a signed number.